# como solucionar Cannot modify header information – headers already sent

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este código y me muestra dos errores al tratar de subir un archivos .csv en un formulario.
me sale el error Undefined offset y Cannot modify header information – headers already sent.

error 1: Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSN\compara\uploadcxc.php on line 29

error 2: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\CSN\compara\uploadcxc.php:29) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSN\compara\uploadcxc.php on line 35

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
 ?>
 <div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><img src="images/loading.gif" width="109" height="114" ></p>
</div>
<?php
$mes=$_POST['mes'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$fecha=$mes." ".$year;
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']))
    {

     copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['archivo']['name']);

$row = 0;
$fp =fopen ($_FILES['archivo']['name'],"r");
set_time_limit(0);

while ($data =fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ","))
{
$num = count ($data);
print "<br>";
$row++;
$insertar="INSERT INTO cxc (cliente, nombre, moneda, saldoinicial, cargos, creditos, saldofinal, fecha) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$fecha')"; 

mysql_query($insertar) or die (mysql_error()); 
} 
fclose ($fp); 
unlink($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
header("refresh:3; url=inicio.php");
    }
    else
    {

        header("refresh:3; url=inicio.php");
    }

?>
```

codigo del formulario para subir archivos:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.dif{background-color: #FE2E2E; color: #FFFFFF; font: 100% sans-serif;}
.i{ background-color: #D8D8D8;}
.t{background-color: #1C1C1C; color: #FFF;}

table {
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin-left: 0%;
}
tr, td {

   text-align: left;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding: 0.3em;
   caption-side: bottom;
}
caption {
   padding: 0.3em;
   color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
tr {
   background: #eee;
}
input[type=text], select {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

td:hover, td:active {
    background-color: #069A12;
    color:white;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

    <table border='1'>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.location='menu.php?$t=1'"><td>Subir Archivo CXC.</td></tr>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.location='menu.php?$t=2'"><td>Subir Archivo Contabilidad</tr>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.location='menu.php?$t=3'"><td>Comparativa CXC/ Contabilidad</td></tr>
    </table>
<?php
include ('conexion.php'); 
if (isset ($_GET['$t'])) {
    if ($_GET['$t']==1) {


    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
body{background-color:#C6D9E1;}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkFile() {
        var fileElement = document.getElementById("archivo");
        var fileExtension = "";
        if (fileElement.value.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
            fileExtension = fileElement.value.substring(fileElement.value.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileElement.value.length);
        }
        if (fileExtension == "csv") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Favor de cargar un archivo con extension *.CSV");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="cargar" action="uploadcxc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkFile();">
  <div align="center">
    <p><font size="+2">Cargar cuentas por cobrar </font>   </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <select name='mes'>
        <option value='#'>Seleccione...</option>
        <option>ENERO</option>
        <OPTION>FEBRERO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>MARZO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>ABRIL</OPTION>
        <OPTION>MAYO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>JUNIO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>JULIO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>AGOSTO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>SEPTIEMBRE</OPTION>
        <OPTION>OCTUBRE</OPTION>
        <OPTION>NOVIEMBRE</OPTION>
        <OPTION>DICIEMBRE</OPTION>
    </select>
     <select name='year'>
        <?php 
        for ($i=2014; $i<=2030; $i++) {
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        }  ?>
    </select>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Cargar archivo *.CSV de cuentas por cobrar</p>

      <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" />
      <input type="submit" value="Cargar" />
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
<?php
}//$_GET==1

if($_GET['$t']==2)
{
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
body{background-color:#C6D9E1;}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkFile() {
        var fileElement = document.getElementById("alumno");
        var fileExtension = "";
        if (fileElement.value.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
            fileExtension = fileElement.value.substring(fileElement.value.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileElement.value.length);
        }
        if (fileExtension == "csv") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Favor de cargar un archivo con extension *.CSV");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="cargar" action="uploadcon.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkFile();">
  <div align="center">
    <p><font size="+2">Cargar archivo de contabilidad </font>   </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <select name='mes'>
        <option value='#'>Seleccione...</option>
        <option>ENERO</option>
        <OPTION>FEBRERO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>MARZO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>ABRIL</OPTION>
        <OPTION>MAYO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>JUNIO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>JULIO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>AGOSTO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>SEPTIEMBRE</OPTION>
        <OPTION>OCTUBRE</OPTION>
        <OPTION>NOVIEMBRE</OPTION>
        <OPTION>DICIEMBRE</OPTION>
    </select>

    <select name='year'>
        <?php 
        for ($i=2014; $i<=2030; $i++) {
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        }  ?>
    </select>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Cargar archivo *.CSV de contabilidad</p>

      <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" />
      <input type="submit" value="Cargar" />
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
<?php
}//$_GET==2

if ($_GET['$t']==3) {
    ?>

<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
include ('conexion.php');
$estilo='i';
$f=mysql_query("select fecha from conta group by fecha");
?>
<select name='fecha'>
    <option>Seleccione...</option>
<?php
while ($f1=mysql_fetch_array($f))
{
?>
<option><?php echo $f1[0];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Ir'>
</form>

<?php
}
  }//isset $_GET

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
echo $fecha;?>
<table border='1'>
<tr class='t'><td>CUENTA</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>SALDO FINAL CONTA</td><td>SALDO FINAL CXC</td></tr>
<?php
$q=mysql_query("select cuenta, saldofinal, nombre from conta where fecha='$fecha'");
//echo "select cuenta, saldofinal, nombre from conta where fecha='$fecha'";
while ($q1=mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
{
    $w=mysql_query("select cliente, saldofinal from cxc where fecha='$fecha'");
        while ($w1=mysql_fetch_array($w))
        {
            if($q1[0]==$w1[0])
            {
                if($q1[1]!=$w1[1])
                {
                    $estilo='dif';
                }
                else
                    {$estilo='i';}
                //echo "cuenta conta ".$q1[0]."cuenta cxc  ".$w1[0]. "saldo final conta".$q1[1]."saldo final cxc".$w1[1]."<br>";
                ?> 
            <tr class='<?php echo $estilo ?>'><td><?php echo $q1[0] ?></td><td><?php echo $q1[2]?></td><td><?php echo number_format($q1[1],2) ?></td><td><?php echo number_format($w1[1],2) ?></td></tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
}
?>
<tr>
<td align='center'>
<input type="image" name="imprimir" src="images/print.png" onclick="window.print(); return false;"/></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
}//$_POST
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, no utilices fotos o imágenes de mensajes de error. En su lugar copia los mensajes y añádelos a la pregunta

Comment: agrega los errores como texto, no como imagenes

Comment: por que se tienen que subir los errores como texto y no como imagen ?

Comment: Para que se puedan cortar y pegar; para que los buscadores puedan indexarlos y así otros usuarios puedan localizar este mismo error; y para que lean mejor... :)

Comment: Añade el código de tu formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes utilizar `header` si ya has mandado datos previamente. Ya que si lo has hecho ya has especificado el encabezado HTTP.

Puedes leer más al respecto [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).

Puesto que parece que quieres redireccionar en cualquier caso, lo que te recomendaría es hacer un redirect via javascript.

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
 ?>
 <div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><img src="images/loading.gif" width="109" height="114" ></p>
</div>
<?php
$mes=$_POST['mes'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$fecha=$mes." ".$year;
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'])) {
    copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['archivo']['name']);

    $row = 0;
    $fp =fopen ($_FILES['archivo']['name'],"r");
    set_time_limit(0);

    while ($data =fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ","))
    {
    $num = count ($data);
    print "<br>";
    $row++;
    $insertar="INSERT INTO cxc (cliente, nombre, moneda, saldoinicial, cargos, creditos, saldofinal, fecha) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$fecha')"; 

    mysql_query($insertar) or die (mysql_error()); 
    } 
    fclose ($fp); 
    unlink($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
}

print "<script>window.setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/inicio.php' }, 3000);</script>";

?>
```

Comment: @jasieltorres Hola, tu idea es insertar el registro y a la vez (después) redireccionar? Por cierto, mira de reescribir tu comentario. No se considera adecuado que todo esté en mayúsculas

Comment: Hola!!
Necesito redireccionar a una página después de que se cumpla una condición, y se inserten los datos en mi tabla de la BD según lo que he leído direccionas con:
header("location:.......");

pero para que esto funcione debe ir al inicio de todas las cabeceras, pero yo necesito que primero se realice una condición y según si esta se cumple entonces que se haga la redirección.

Comment: por eso mi código esta así con los header al final pero fue cuando me boto mi error , con ayuda de tu código el primero que me pusiste de ejemplo si me redirecciono pero a la hora de checar mi base de datos no se realizo el insert

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta. Podrías probar así? (por cierto, mira de borrar tu primer comentario :))

Comment: Muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba si me funciono así