# Warning : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un formulario para recuperar contraseñas (Todo bien de hecho funciona) pero me encuentro con este problema:

**Warning
: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by**

El formulario se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como te darás cuenta estoy tratando de que el usuario actualice su contraseña pero limitándolo a **8 caracteres** entonces tengo el siguiente código (**Que es el archivo donde el formulario llega)**:

```
<?php
```

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

```
function validatePassword1($password1)
{
    // Longitud mininma 
    if (strlen($password1) < 4) {
        return false;
    }
    // Caracteres de "A" a la "Z" 
    else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/", $password1)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePassword2($password1, $password2)
{
    // No coinciden
    if ($password1 != $password2) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}


//Validación de datos enviados


if (isset($_POST['newpass1'])) {
    $pass = $_POST['newpass1'];
} else {
    $pass = "";
}
$passValue = "";

if (isset($_POST['newpass2'])) {
    $pass2 = $_POST['newpass2'];
} else {
    $pass2 = "";
}
$pass2Value = "";


if (!validatePassword1($pass)) {
    $pass = "error";
}
if (!validatePassword2($pass, $pass2)) {
    $pass2 = "error";
}

if ($pass == 'error' && $pass2 == 'error') {
    header("Location: ../pagina_resetear_contraseña.php?mensaje_error2");
}
```

}
?>

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo "<div class='bg-warning mb-2 col border rounded'><p class=' text-dark h-25'> <strong>* Los datos son incorrectos</strong></p></div>";
} else {
    "";
}






if (isset($_POST['valorID'])) {
    $ID = $_POST['valorID'];
}
if (isset($_POST['newpass1'])) {
    $newPass = $_POST['newpass1'];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET pass = '$newPass' WHERE ID = '$ID' ";

    // $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user='$userD' and tokenUser='$tokenD'";

    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    //$datos2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);

    if ($resultado2 == true && $resultado2 != "") {
        echo "<div class='bg-primary mb-2 rounded-top text-light col-lg-12 col-sm-12'>";
        echo "<strong>Tu contraseña se a actualizado, accede con tu nueva contraseña</strong>";
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
}

?>
<form action='/area_login/login_verificar.php' method='POST'>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <p class="etiquetas_crear_cuenta  col-5 float-left"><strong>Nombre:</strong></p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" name="username" id="exampleInputEmail1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="etiquetas_crear_cuenta  col-5 float-left"><strong>Contraseña:</strong></p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" name="password" id="exampleInputEmail1">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='login'>Enviar</button>

    <div class=" col-4  " id="Cuadro_olvidar">
        <a href="/area_login/pagina_recuperar_usuario.php" class="d-block">Olvidaste tu usuario</a>
        <a href="/area_login/pagina_recuperar_contraseña.php" class="d-block">Olvidaste tu contraseña</a>
        <a href="/area_login/pagina_crear_cuentas.php" class="d-block">Crear cuenta</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Pero el error me lo marca en la **linea 59** justo donde esta el **"header Location"**

Yo necesito ese **"header Location"** para que el archivo **primero me valide** las funciones esas que puse de que; **"Si puso 8 caracteres entonces si actualízale la contraseña si no por medio del HEADER regrésamelo a la pagina anterior y envíale un error por GET**

Sin embargo la contraseña se actualiza y arriba me sale el warning de: **Warning
: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by**

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?** Porque de hecho este problema de ese warning lo tengo en otro archivo solo que no eh preguntado nada sobre ello y eh pasado de largo de el pero en esta ocasión si me tiene atorado...

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como solucionar Cannot modify header information – headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249084/como-solucionar-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: Es un problema bastante común de los usuarios de PHP, en pocas palabras, primero procesa los datos, o manda el redirect, antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador. Buscar más al respecto: [PHP Headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+headers+already+sent)